# Processing lines and filling fields

Tags: javascript, onclick, innerhtml, referenceerror

I read and search and study, but can't seem to write any JS out of my own head - this should be really simple but it will not work. I keep getting an error about an undefined variable "madlib7.html:411 Uncaught ReferenceError: populatefields is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick"

I start with some urls that I paste into a textarea, then I click a button and first it splits the text into individual lines and stores them in variables. Next, I want to split each line by spaces and populate fields in an HTML form with select words from the resulting array via the use of innerhtml.

I know there is some way of looping through the processes, but I have not figured out how to do that yet so for now I am writing it all out the long way. I have not been able to figure out how to address the error message 'ReferenceError' from above.

```
Thanks for any and all help

Paul

populatefields(day1, location1, streamid1)  {
document.getElementById('PanLinks').value.split('\n');
        
var streamInfoLine1 = resultArr[0];
var streamInfoLine2 = resultArr[1];
var streamInfoLine3 = resultArr[2];
var streamInfoLine1 = resultArr[3];
var streamInfoLine2 = resultArr[4];
var streamInfoLine3 = resultArr[5];
var streamInfoLine1 = resultArr[6];
var streamInfoLine2 = resultArr[7];
var streamInfoLine3 = resultArr[8];
        
        
streamInfoLine1.split(' ');
var day1 = resultArr[0];
var location1 = resultArr[3];
var streamID1 = resultArr[4];
document.getElementById("location1").innerHTML= location1;
document.getElementById("time1").innerHTML= day1;
document.getElementById("streamid1").innerHTML= streamID1;
  }
```

Comment: According to the message, what "variable" was undefined?

Answer (score 0):

could you use stackoverflow built in code sandbox to include all your code in html, javascript code? it seems like the issue is on your html file `madlib7.html`, where your `onclick` listener isn't defined on the button. nor did I see anything from your code that indicates any event listener has been setup to perform that button task. so it's hard to help debug what exactly it is.

Comment: Thanks, David. I'll fall back and regroup to present a better question.

Comment: Hi David, I've searched high and low and not found anything that even mentions the "stackoverflow built in code sandbox" not even in the help section!

Comment: you can just go to code sandbox and put the code there then paste the link here. so I can review it.  https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: Here's the sandbox link - I worked on the script near the bottom of the page and added some comments as to what I am thinking that each line does. Right now the error I am getting is that there is an extra closing parenthesis in the statement that contains the eventlistener. (line 241) 

https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-neumann-fc8bz?file=/index.html

Comment: are you sure you saved the project? when I open the link I don't see anything there.

Comment: Yep, I see the code when I click the link, however, I need to toggle the viewing mode on the output before it appears. Then it seems to be fine.

Comment: I looked again, I can't see anyplace to click save on codesandbox, if I attempt to close the window it says I will lose my work. Also the only template I saw that looked applicable is the vanilla.js even though this is an HTML document.

Comment: try using codepen then. that should work.